# Are there materials or molecules where fast internal conversion is desirable?

Tags: physical-chemistry

For light-emitting devices fast internal conversion is typically considered as a downside as it competes with fluorescence and phosphorescence. A low internal conversion rate is thus typically desired for molecules in applications in light emitting devices, like OLED's, and molecules with high photoluminescence quantum yield are searched for.

I am wondering if there are materials or applications, where the opposite is the case. I.e. where one looks for molecules with fast internal conversion. Are there properties/materials that benefit from fast internal conversion of a molecule?

Comment: Sunscreen compounds need to have fast internal conversion if i understand correctly.

Comment: Intersystem crossing is more important if you want to form triplets, fast internal conversion can prevent forming triplets or fluorescence by competition. Fast internal conversion means that the molecule does nothing but heat up the surroundings.

Comment: The old joke is that only 10% of all substances fluoresce and they are the wrong 10%! In photoacoustic spectroscopy and related techniques, you can make use of the non-radiative pathways. But for purposes such as sensitive analytical detection of substances, fluorescence is usually highly desirable. Phosphorescence not so much. If you really need minimal fluorescence, you can usually quench fluorescence by adding a quencher: oxygen, xenon, nitromethane, various heavy metal ions, etc.

Comment: @porphyrin That is the common knowledge. I am wondering if there is anything else that can be achieved by internal conversion. I am not aware of particularly useful applications, but I'm not certain if there are truly none. It could be a simple lack of knowledge on my side.

Comment: One can use the OLED as a lumiphore as a continuous light source (e.g. ceiling of an office, wall of a staircase) where slow processes are not *this much* problematic. This contrasts to applications where short reaction times/high switching rates are desired (e.g. displays of TV sets, cellular phones). The design of HTL, ETL and emitter layer (for red, green, and blue pixels in one cell phone/TV screen, one uses different emitter materials each) of the two differ; e.g. for longevity of the device, TVs often stack two layers of red/green/blue pixels on top of each other.

Comment: @Buttonwood, Not so, high fluorescence yield is essential for dye lasers and intense (laser) pumping due to their short excited state lifetimes.

Comment: I would add that if you are using Raman spectroscopy a low fluorescence yield is most advantageous.  Photothermal methods are useful way of studying excited states, the heat generated distorts a probe beam etc.  see this paper Beddard & Yorke, Appl. Spectroscopy, 2016, vol 70,p 1292 , https://doi.org/10.1177/0003702816653927

Comment: @porphyrin Ok.  Makes sense as to keep the states differently populated than mere room temperature and its resulting Boltzmann distribution would predict.

Comment: When you create new tags, it would be much appreciated that you also add usage guidance for them.